# Mockery with Laravel don't mocks a method

Tags: laravel, testing, mockery

I use Laravel 5.5 and try to mock a public method of an class, which is used inside this class:

```
class ToTest {
  public function filters() {
    return 'original';
  }

  public function callMe() {
    return $this->filters();
  }
}
```

This is my Testcode:

```
public function it_should_call_bla_bla()
{
  $mock = $this->mock(ToTest::class);
  $mock->shouldReceive('filters')->andReturn('not orignial');

  $toTest = app(ToTest::class);
  print_r($toTest->callMe());
}

private function mock($class)
{
  $mock = Mockery::mock(app($class))->makePartial();

  $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

  return $mock;
}
```

`$toTest->callMe()` returns `original`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you create your mock out of an object instead of a class, correct code, to meet your requirements would be this:

```
        $mock = Mockery::mock($class)->makePartial();
```

What happened is you were mocking object. When `ToTest` object was already initialized, mocking has overridden only `filters` method, leaving `callMe` intact. If you try to dump `print_r($toTest->filters());` with your old code, it will return `"not original"`.